# Is this a possible solution to this Diophantine Eqution?

Tags: systems-of-equations, pythagorean-triples

So for reference, I have no previous experience with Diophantine equations, but for this particular set I believe I have found something that works.I also didn't exactly set out to solve this system, more stumbled across it.
This Diophantine equation is essentially this:

$$A^2+B^2 =C^2\\
A^2+D^2 =E^2 \\
B^2+D^2 =F^2\\ 
B^2+E^2 =G^2.$$

So, my mind should have first went to the fact that these all look like the pythagorean equation, but it didn't so I solved them all for zero and created an augmented matrix to try and get some more information. This told me that

$G^2, F^2$, and $E^2$ are all free choices, $A^2=G^2-F^2, B^2=G^2-E^2, D^2=-G^2+F^2+E^2$, and $C^2=2G^2-F^2-E^2$. This is similarly awkward, but I figured as long as there are 3 squares that add up to each other they should be able to get a solution. So, I tried setting $G=5, F=4$, and $E=3$ and it worked. But these aren't the only set of numbers that would work, they could be any Pythagorean triple $(x, y, z)$ and as long as $G=x, F=y, E=z$ and $x$ is the hypotenuse. From this, I found that $A=z, B=y, C=x$, and $D=0$. This works when plugged into the original set of equations.

$$z^2+y^2 =x^2 \\
z^2+0 =z^2 \\
y^2+0 =y^2 \\
y^2+z^2 =x^2$$

These are only the set of positive integers that are solutions, I'm sure there are many more but like I said I more stumbled across this. Is this correct, or am I spewing nonsense?

Comment: Not having checked your calculation with the matrix but what do you mean by *trivial*? If trivial means $ = 0$ as it usually does then it would imply $A, B, C, D$ be equal to zero as well if your subsequent expressions are correct...

Comment: Sorry, I meant that they were a free choice, not trivial. I have edited my post to fix this, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: It cannot be done with primitive triples because $A$ and $B$ must be of opposite parity and your third equation is the sum of two even numbers (assuming $A$ is odd and $B$ is even). I can find many answers to questions like this by hand but this one would require a computer program if it is solvable.  Can you re-arrange the equations somehow?

Comment: Why do they need to be of opposite parity? Right now in the third equation, using a primitive triplet it will always boil down to adding zero, so if that violates the rules of the equation/the problem then rearranging might be possible.

Comment: In a primitive triple, $C$ must be odd so $A$ and $B$ cannot both be odd or both be even.

Comment: Sorry, I had a misunderstanding of what a primitive triplet was. But I don't understand why it has to be made of primitive tirplets, unless I am wrong any pythagorean triplet should fulfill the system. Sorry for all the questions, I am not trying to be critical, I just have a legitimate misunderstanding.